# Trying to Identify Stone Statue

Tags: stones

I was given this statue at an estate sale and have no idea what it is or where it is from. Any help would be appreciated.

Update: I did some googling and it seems to look like [Mayan stone](https://www.liveauctioneers.com/item/56220650_mayan-stone-tenon-monkey-head-ex-arte-primitivo).

[image: Front]

[image: Back]

[image: Top]

[image: Bottom]

Comment: Are there any clues to how it was made, or whether it is a relic vs. recent art?  I'm thinking things like whether weight and surface markings indicate it's carved from a solid block of stone vs. being a casting or made from clay.

Comment: @fixer1234 I added pictures of the top and the bottom. My guess is that it is a solid block of stone. Maybe the little indent in the top was how it was held in place while carved. It is very heavy.

Comment: Tineye didn't find anything similar.  Google Images identified it as a "carving" and showed "visually similar" images that covered every form of carving on a mineral material.  This object apparently isn't something for which sufficiently similar images have been posted and indexed on the Internet.  There's a chance that someone knowledgeable could spot this post, but it might be worth going directly to expert sources.  If we start with the assumption that it's an antiquity, there are some web sites, typically run by museums and university departments, that may be able to help.  (cont'd)

Comment: Some have identification tools, others describe how to submit identification requests.  I put "identify antiquities" into Google, and the result looked like that might be a promising source of some leads.